# How exactly does Shell Bell work?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

As Bulbapedia stands:

> Whenever the Pokémon holding it deals damage, it restores 1/8 of the damage dealt as HP.

This means to me that every time I deal damage to an enemy my Pokemon recovers a bit of HP. But that's not true, because it seems that the **Shell Bell** doesn't work on OHKO moves neither on the last move that make the enemy faint.

Is this right? Please, let me know how it works, I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've just realized that I was using **Shell Bell** on a Pokemon with **Sheer Force**. I've checked Bulbapedia again and found this:

> If (and only if) a move is boosted by the effect of Sheer Force, it
>   will no longer trigger item or Ability effects that activate after
>   attacking. This includes the effects of Shell Bell.